# Gammu and a Raspberry Pi

Tags: sms, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gammu

I installed gammu-smsd. After a whole lot of grappling with permissions and tearing hair I finally got the RunOnReceive script to run without exiting on an error.

In its current truncated form it says

```
message=$SMS_1_TEXT

echo message is {$message} >> /var/sys.log
```

and `$message` comes up blank .... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's actually empty from Gammu SMSD? As per [documentation](http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/run.html#environment) it can be empty for some message types. Using `DECODED_1_TEXT` might be better fit, depending what you actually want.

Anyway to debug, you can put `env` command to your script, this way you will get listed all environment variables.